# Compare files with the same name

Tags: macos, bash, for-loop

I created script to compare files in folder (with the name .jpg and without it BUT with the same NAME).The problem that script searches for files in ONE directory ,not in SubDirectories!How i can fix it?

```
for f in *
do
  for n in *.jpg
do
tempfile="${n##*/}"
    echo "Processing"
echo "${tempfile%.*}"
echo "$f"
  if [[ "${tempfile%.*}" = $f ]]
then
  echo "This files have the same name!"
//do something here
else
echo "No files"
  fi
done
done
```

Comment: are you trying to detect the same-name files in the same directory, or are you tyring to find them in any directory? Ex. "./a/b/c/foo.jpg" and "./d/e/foo"

Comment: i am trying to find same-name files in any directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires bash version 4 for associative arrays.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob extglob
declare -A jpgs

for jpg in **/*.jpg; do 
    name=$(basename "${jpg%.jpg}")
    jpgs["$name"]=$jpg
done

for f in **/!(*.jpg); do 
    name=$(basename "$f")
    if [[ -n ${jpgs["$name"]} ]]; then 
        echo "$f has the same name as ${jpgs["$name"]}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Is it possible to add support to also check name of directory(only one directory) in which this file located?For example, if Desktop/a/test.jpg  == Myfiles/a/test.jpg then it should be good!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using  `find`

```
find . -type f -name "*.sh" -printf "%f\n" | cut -f1 -d '.' > jpg.txt

while read line
do
  find . -name "$line.*" -print
done < jpg.txt
```